# Error of Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I have table of stock with DOCDate field and it has datatype as datetime, when i am running my query, it shows me error

> 'Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.'

My query is

```
insert into SSPERPStock (LinkID, DocNo, DocDate, VoucherType, ProductID, Weight, AL, InEdit, CreatedU‌​serId) 
values (IDENT_CURRENT('SSPERPDailyInkConsumptionTransaction'),'DOC1001','2013-02-‌​14','ICPacked',8,5,'L',0,GETDATE())
```

What can be the solution of this mistry??

Comment: The mystery is primarily around your code and query, as you haven't provided either yet.

Comment: It would help if we could see the SQL query you are running.

Comment: insert into SSPERPStock(LinkID,DocNo,DocDate,VoucherType,ProductID,Weight,AL,InEdit,CreatedUserId) values(IDENT_CURRENT('SSPERPDailyInkConsumptionTransaction'),'DOC1001','2013-02-14','ICPacked',8,5,'L',0,GETDATE())

Comment: the above one is my runtime query

Comment: The error is in the last column, So some column called " CreatedU‌​serId" is in int and you want to insert Date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to add a date (`GETDATE()`) to your column `CreatedU‌​serId`

```
insert into SSPERPStock (... , CreatedU‌​serId) 
values (... , GETDATE())
```

which is probably an `int` and not what you wanted to do in the first place.

Comment: You are absolutely right dear, it was my fault and i havent checked it, well thanks for this