# Error "Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to datetime is not allowed" occurred while inserting data to database using dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a  repository class with a method

```
using Dapper;
public int Execute(string query, object arguments)
    {
        return Connection.Execute(query,arguments);
    }
```

In another program, I try to run an insert query.

```
dbOps.Execute(qry, new
                            {
                                transType = unp.TransType,
                                itemCode = unp.ItemCode,
                                itemQty = unp.ItemQty,
                                itemUM = unp.UnitMeasure,
                                itemSite = unp.ItemSite,
                                itemLoc1 = unp.ItemLocation1,
                                itemLoc2 = unp.ItemLocation2,
                                transRmk = unp.TransRmks,
                                transEffDate = unp.TransEffDate, //is DateTime
                                transDate = unp.TransDate, //is DateTime
                                cimStatus = unp.CimStatus,
                                cimBatchNo = unp.CimBatchNo,
                                transID = unp.TransID,
                                cimLoadDate = unp.CimLoadDate
                            });
```

unp Class:

```
internal class unp
    {
        public string TransType { get; set; }
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemQty { get; set; }
        public string UnitMeasure { get; set; }
        public string ItemSite { get; set; }
        public string ItemLocation1 { get; set; }
        public string ItemLocation2 { get; set; }
        public string TransRmks { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransEffDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransDate { get; set; }
        public byte CimStatus { get; set; }
        public string CimBatchNo { get; set; }
        public string TransID { get; set; }
        public object CimLoadDate { get; set; }

        public string SourceFile { get; set; }
        public string JournalId { get; set; }
    }
```

Query String:

```
string qry = @"INSERT INTO [Transaction]
                                 VALUES(@transType,@itemCode,@itemQty,@itemUM,@itemSite,@itemLoc1,@itemLoc2,@transRmk,
                                 @transEffDate,@transDate,@cimStatus,@cimBatchNo,@transID,@cimLoadDate)"
```

Im getting an exception:

> Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to datetime is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Any Ideas I can resolve this? or Do I have to impose `Dapper` to multiple projects?

Comment: did you declare variables as datetime in both your database and object classes? can you show us your query?

Comment: Database DataTypes are `DateTime`

Comment: @HEXXED show declaration of all fields those you are using in parameters

Comment: @MeerDeen The Parameters are anonymous. Just strongly typed to match the parameters  on the query string.

Comment: @HEXXED while inserting the records is there values in the unp.TransEffDate, unp.TransDate, or they ar null

Comment: @MeerDeen nope it has values and not null. Its valid a DateTime

Comment: @Hexxed cimLoadDate type in sql server ?

Comment: @Hexxed  i think you have taken this as datetime in sqlserver and here this is taken as object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144511/discussion-between-hexxed-and-meer-deen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this .

change type of CimLoadDate from object type to DateTime. because it is dateTime in your database

```
public Datetime CimLoadDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your query columns of table may mismatches .Use this link it may useful

[Error of Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873575/error-of-implicit-conversion-from-data-type-datetime-to-int-is-not-allowed-use)